# Could the electromagnetic field (EMF) from a power station disrupt wireless signals?

Tags: wireless, electromagnetic, emf

I know that power stations can generate an electromagnetic field, but is that field strong enough to disrupt nearby wireless signals, such as Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, cell service, etc?

I'm sure that, in practice, this isn't an issue. But if you had a communication facility full of extremely sensitive equipment (think military or government), would you want the facility's power supply to be off-site?

I'm asking for a writing project, so "soft" science is okay.

Comment: The electromagnetic field is likely quite strong. However it is predominantly at low frequency, i.e. 50 or 60 Hz

Comment: Unlikely because of the totally different frequency band.

Comment: However, some lab equipment might be affected, however, the scientists can probably shield it by themselves.

Comment: Although not a source that directly answers your question, the book *"Human Interaction with Electromagnetic Fields"* by Poljak & Cvetkovic´ has a section called, ***"Assessment of External Electric and Magnetic Fields at Low Frequencies"***, which covers power lines and substations and may be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not generally. Power stations generate signals at 60 (50) Hz, while 'wireless' signals start from AM radio (~ 1 MHz) up to many GHz. A sensitive radio will have a front-end filter that prevents any 60 Hz signals from getting through upsetting the processing of the desired signals.

There are some harmonics and noise generated from the use of the 60 Hz, but even those are filtered at the source and don't cause long-range interference.

A practical Faraday cage doesn't help much with 60 Hz interference.

Answer (score 0):

If one really cares about protecting sensitive equipment, they make Faraday Cage and place all the equipment inside it.

Alternatively, if one had equipment that produces lots of electromagnetic interference (EMI) they could place the equipment in a Faraday Cage to contain any radiated EMI.

Typically, one can convert an entire room into a Faraday Cage by lining the walls, ceiling, and possibly floor with either metal mesh or sheet metal (typically copper, but others can work also).  The cage is then typically connected to earth ground.

A metal cage will block all electromagnetic signals from entering or leaving the enclosed area.  Though it's unlikely that 60Hz power would interfere much with radio equipment, a generator could in theory be enclosed in a large mesh cage.  It probably needs to be mesh rather than solid to allow for airflow on the heat exchangers/radiators.